# how to turn off phone ringer for incoming calls?

Tags: android

How does one turn off phone ringer for incoming calls? Can this be done programmatically? Right now I am using below code but it's not working:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```